# Access rights for Farm account in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, farm-admin

My SharePoint 2013 farm already have farm admin. account and farm are working fine. However, we need one more account same like farm admin. which will ONLY schedule Timer jobs. However, my question is what is the list of access/rights I need to give to 2nd farm admin. same like 1st farm admin. I have an idea of below access rights, but it seems that I am missing many.

- local administrator
- shell administrator
- the sysadmin fixed role on SQL

Answer (score 6):

**The server farm account requires the following permissions:**

- It must have domain user account permissions.
- Membership in the `WSS_ADMIN_WPG` Windows security group for the SharePoint Foundation 2013 Timer service.
- Membership in `WSS_RESTRICTED_WPG` for the Central Administration and Timer service application pools.
- Membership in `WSS_WPG` for the Central Administration application pool.
- `Dbcreator` fixed server role.
- `Securityadmin` fixed server role.
- `db_owner` for all SharePoint databases.
- Membership in the `WSS_CONTENT_APPLICATION_POOLS` role for the SharePoint server farm configuration database.
- Membership in the `WSS_CONTENT_APPLICATION_POOLS` role for the SharePoint_Admin content database.

Read more at [Account permissions and security settings in SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: You are welcome, Please don't forget to **Mark** and **Upvote** the correct answer in case it helped you. Thanks!